# N:M Relation Syntax Error in code

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

I have this SQL (for MySQL):

```
create table apartmentcaretakers
(
apartmentID int,
caretakerID int,
PRIMARY KEY (apartmentID, caretakerID),
FOREIGN KEY (apartmentID) REFERENCES apartments(apartmentID),
FOREIGN KEY (caretakerID) REFERENCES caretakers(caretakerID)
)engine = innodb;
```

The error that I cat:
SQL syntax error near 'references apartments(apartmentID), foreign key caretakerID references caretakers'

This is properly some minor mistake on my part, but could someone please point it out?

EDIT: After some coding and rerunning, the error is 1064.  Which I can understand why it didn't really help, as it's a broad spectrum error.

Comment: This problem solved it self, after I went for a dive through the endless waves of my brain, and discovered that some one had stolen my parentheses :) But thx anyway for you help...

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me aswell.

Make sure your referenced tables also use the INNODB engine. Use the following query to check that: `SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Name = 'xxx'`

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE apartments (
    -> apartmentID int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL) ENGINE = innodb;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE caretakers (
    -> caretakerID int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL) ENGINE = innodb;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE apartmentcaretakers (
    -> apartmentID int,
    -> caretakerID int,
    -> PRIMARY KEY (apartmentID, caretakerID),
    -> FOREIGN KEY ac_fk_apartments_id (apartmentID) REFERENCES apartments (apartmentID),
    -> FOREIGN KEY ac_fk_caretakers_id(caretakerID) REFERENCES caretakers (caretakerID)
    -> ) ENGINE = innodb;

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: Hmm. So you can create the first two tables ("apartments" and "carettakers")? And they have the INNODB engine? `mysql> SHOW ENGINES` does list InnoDB correctly? Just guessing now :) Could you provide the "DESC" output of both your referenced tables?